# Why isn't the Linux Kernel Image read-only by default?

Tags: permissions, kernel

I installed FUSE last week, and ran into issues running guest mount.  The application tries to read the kernel image from user space.  OK, fine.  A chmod 755, and I'm in business.  Still..I'd like to know.  What is the technical reason that the kernel installs this way by default?  Why not world readable?

```
-rw------- 1 root root  7104112 Dec 11 09:36 vmlinuz-4.4.0-104-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  7141424 Feb 12 19:57 vmlinuz-4.4.0-116-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  7144816 Apr  2 14:05 vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
```

I can't be the only one this has caused problems for.

Comment: Ubuntu, presumably? It's 755 on a CentOS system I had.

Comment: It's 755 on my Fedora system, too.

Comment: This should be installed as world readable as default. Maybe check your umask?

Comment: Yes it's an Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 2):

There are no problems with your installation, umask or something.

For Ubuntu:

> This mode change is "by design". For local admins that what to relax
> this restriction, you can use `dpkg-statoverride`:
>
> ```
> sudo dpkg-statoverride --update --add root root 0644 /boot/vmlinuz-$(uname -r)
> ```
>
> To have this automatically happen with each new kernel, create
> `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/statoverride` (don't forget to chmod +x):
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> version="$1" # passing the kernel version is required 
> [ -z "${version}" ] && exit 0
> dpkg-statoverride --update --add root root 0644 /boot/vmlinuz-${version}
> ```

My opinion is that's one of the correct solutions; this is a (slightly fixed and formatted) quote of comment by Kees Cook from https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/759725. Check that out for more info about why it was made so and other things.